# While submitting a list jquery is not able to get the selected check box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list with checkbox. I am submitting the checked rows but before submitting i am validating the list whether it have any checked values or not, for that i have written a jQuery.

```
    jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#newDeliveredAll").click(function () {
               if(jQuery('.notClosedCase').prop('checked')) {
              jQuery(".notClosedCase").click(function(){
                    if(jQuery(".notClosedCase").length == jQuery(".notClosedCase:checked").length) {
                        jQuery("#newDeliveredAll").attr("checked", "checked");
                    } else {
                        jQuery("#newDeliveredAll").removeAttr("checked");
                    }

                });
              return true;
          }else {
                alert(" Please select atleast one order ");
                return false;
            }
         });
       });
```

But the issue which i am facing is, when the first row is not `checked`even tho if i have checked multiple rows and left the first row, its showing the same `alert` written in else `part`

Comment: Please give the jsfiddle link. Because we need html structure you have used.

Comment: Paste your HTML also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You checked condition like below.

```
if(jQuery('.notClosedCase').prop('checked'))
```

This condition is true when all the checkbox is checked which has **notClosedCase** class. 
If any of the checkbox not checked, it is return false. so only you got false block.
Please use below condition.

```
if (jQuery('.notClosedCase:checked').length > 0)
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5p12fnqd/)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks (jQuery('.notClosedCase:checked').length > 0) that is exactly what was required.